# How to display only selected list of items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to populate a list something like below:

```
<select name="prescription"  multiple="multiple">
    <c:forEach items="${medicines}" var="current">
        <option value="${current}"><c:out value="${current}" /></option>
    </c:forEach>

</select>
```

I am trying to populate only the selected list in another similar for each loop. But i am not getting  how to do it. Can any one help me with it?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you sure this should be tagged just `javascript` and `jquery`?

Comment: How can i display the selected items in the above medicines list?

Comment: <c:forEach items="${medicines}" var="current" >
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
   <c:out value="${current}" ></c:out>
                    
  </div>
        </div>
</c:forEach>

Comment: Trying like this but i am getting all the list contents from medicine

Comment: What JS library are you using? This doesn't look like you're using jQuery

Comment: Is it possible to pass list from javascript to JSP and display it in JSP? If so can you please suggest me how to do

Comment: what selected items you want to show ??? Just add them in the list

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are showing some list from the controller to the jsp page , You can proceed with either of these 2 ways

1. Add the only items in the list that you want to show 
   for example :

assuming that the list medicine has all the parameters

```
        List<String> medicine = Your-List;

        List<String> final_medicine = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0; i < medicine.size(); i++)
    {

              if(your-condition-here){

                  final_medicine.add(medicine.get(i));
             }
    }

request.setAttribute("medicine",final_medicine);
```

The second way could be getting the values in the jsp itself using the

```
<select name="prescription"  multiple="multiple">
    <c:forEach items="${medicines}" var="current">
            <c:if test="${medicines eq your-condition}>
               <option value="${current}"><c:out value="${current}" /></option>
            </c:if>
    </c:forEach>

</select>
```

If this is something that you require?

Comment: I have a table which contains all my values of form fields.
for example table's 1st column contains form's first field which is a list.
Now this particular table(that contains populated values) is present in Javascript function.
 Now when i click on form's submit, these table values should be passed to controller in MVC so that I can save them to db. 
Now I need to know how can I bind these values  from javascript to form fields.

Comment: Use the <input type="hidden" name="hiddenparam" id="hiddenparam" value=''>
In the JS, set the value of hiddenparam as $('#hiddenparam').val(YOur value from table);
in the controller use : request.getparamter("hiddenparam");

(OR) in your case you can directly get the selected value using request.getparameter("prescription");